# Estoy intentando imprimir el valor del centro del arreglo y tengo la logica en un papelito pero no se como escribirla en Java, soy nueva en arreglos

Tags: java, array

Tarea: Suponga un array con N números enteros generados aleatoriamente y mostrados en pantalla,N debe ser un número impar, mostrar en pantalla el valor que ocupa el centro del array.

Ya genere mi arreglo con numeros aleatorios y para poder coger la posicioni del centro hice que al numero que ponga en tamaño le aumente uno siesque es par y si es impar le mande igual, mi idea era que como las posiciones van de 0 en adelante, al ya tener un arreglo impar mis posiciones serian pares entonces quiero dividir mi ultima posicion para dos e imprimir el valor de esa posicion

por ejemplo tengo un arreglo de 5 de tamaño, entonces las posiciones irian de 0 a 4 y al dividir mi 4 para 2 me da 2 entonces quiero imprimir el valor de esa posicion 2. Como dije ya tengo la logica pero no se como hacer eso en el programa ayuda porfavor.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     
        int tamaño;
        tamaño = 2;
        
        if(tamaño%2==0)
        {
            tamaño+=1;
        }
        else
        {
            tamaño = tamaño;
        }
        int Arreglo [];
        Arreglo = new int [tamaño];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++) 
        {
            
            Arreglo[i]  = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            System.out.print(+Arreglo[i] +"  ");
        }
        System.out.println( );
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < Arreglo.length; i++) 
        {
            int posicion =  Arreglo[i]/2 = 
               
           
        }
        
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De esta manera quedaría dándole forma a tu idea, revisa los comentarios colocados en // que te servirán para entender mejor el programa.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int tamaño=5; //supongamos que el tamaño de tu arreglo es 5 equivale a [0] [1] [2] [3] [4]
        
        int Arreglo[] = new int [tamaño]; //creas el arreglo 
        
        for (int i = 0; i < Arreglo.length; i++) 
        {
            
            Arreglo[i]  = (int)(Math.random()*10); //Ingresas datos aleatorios
            
            if (Arreglo[i]%2==0) { //Preguntamos si el número en esa posicion nos da residuo 0 quiere decir que es par
                int numeropos= Arreglo[i]+1; // Como no queremos pares agregamos +1 y resulta un número impar 
                Arreglo[i]=numeropos; // Devolvemos el valor cambiado al arreglo 
            } 
            
            System.out.print(+Arreglo[i] +"  "); //Imprimimos el arreglo
        }
        
        int numero =  Arreglo[tamaño/2]; // Nos devuelve el numero en la posicion en el centro del arreglo para eso se divide el tamaño entre 2 
         
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("El número en el centro del arreglo es: "+ numero);
    }
```

Saludos.